# Finding 15th and 85th percentile in matlab

Tags: matlab, percentile

I have came up with a matlab code to plot a probability density and a cumulative graph. I have used the matlab to compute the standard deviation and the mean as well. 
My next task is to find the 15th and 85 percentile of the cumulative graph. I tried to use 'prctile (prob, 15)' to calculate the 15th percentile but it does not seem to be the same value as what I have observed from the graph.

Is there any other ways to find the 15th and 85 percentile?

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the 15% and 85% percentile values as you see in your cumulative graph:

```
15_percentile = prob(find(prob<prctile(prob,15),1));
85_percentile = prob(find(prob>prctile(prob,85),1,'last'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the percentile function if you have that statistics toolbox (type help prctile).
http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prctile.html

Alternatively write it yourself! A percentile is simply the data sorted, and the value closest to the percentile you want (for example if you have 1000 values, your 15th percentile will be the (15/100)*1000=150th value! Make sure you sort the data from smallest to largest.

There is a special way to deal with values that fall in between samples, but these depend on the definition you use. Some take the nearest, others take the average between two samples, and some others calculate how close they are to the samples and take a value that is linearly proportional to that.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to calculate a percentile (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile)

The gotcha here is that MatLab and Excel don't agree (Excel uses the definition empployed by the National Institiute of Standards And Technology in the US...also default for R)...worth considering if you swap data and analysis between MatLab and Excel.